# feature.cs file in Nunit Test Project is not created

Tags: c#, specflow

I am trying to create a feature in an NUnit .Net Core project in Visual Studio 2019. Everytime I create one, the feature.cs file is not generated automatically and tells me that the source file could not be found. I have the following in the .csproj . I also tried setting SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator to true but it did not work and I have put it back to False. What do I have missing ?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.1.95" />
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.16.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand the problem. For me, you do not have to touch the csproj file.
Have you tried to create a new class in this project ?